# Website monitor - if site is down, kill the process, contact admin and restart server

Tags: python, bash, server, tornado

My Python-based web server (Tornado module) is pretty complex and keeps going down (seems like usually in the middle of the night), so here's a bash script that kills the process, restarts and emails and txt messages me:

```
#!/bin/bash
NOTIFYEMAIL=<my_email_address>
SMSEMAIL=<cell_phone_number>@<carrier> # ie. pm.sprint.com
SENDEREMAIL=admin@loclahost
SERVER=http://the_website.com/
PAUSE=60
FAILED=0
DEBUG=0

while true 
do
/usr/bin/curl -sSf --max-time 10 $SERVER > /dev/null 2>&1
CS=$?
# For debugging purposes
if [ $DEBUG -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "STATUS = $CS"
    echo "FAILED = $FAILED"
    if [ $CS -ne 0 ]
    then
    echo "$SERVER is down"

    elif [ $CS -eq 0 ]
    then
    echo "$SERVER is up"
    fi
fi

# If the server is down and no alert is sent - alert
if [ $CS -ne 0 ] && [ $FAILED -eq 0 ]
then
    PID=`ps -eaf | grep 'python -m fore.server' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
    FAILED=1
    if [ $DEBUG -eq 1 ]
    then
    echo "$SERVER failed"
    if [[ "" !=  "$PID" ]]
    then
        echo "killing $PID"
        kill -9 $PID
        echo "Starting the server."
        python -m fore.server
    else
        echo "No Python Process Running Locally"
    fi
    fi
    if [ $DEBUG = 0 ]
    then
    echo "$SERVER failed"
    PID=`ps -eaf | grep 'python -m fore.server' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
    if [[ "" !=  "$PID" ]]
    then
        kill -9 $PID
        echo "$SERVER went down $(date)" | /usr/bin/mail -s "$SERVER went down" "$SENDEREMAIL" "$SMSEMAIL" 
        echo "$SERVER went down $(date)" | /usr/bin/mail -s "$SERVER went down" "$SENDEREMAIL" "$NOTIFYEMAIL"
        python -m fore.server
    else
        echo "No Python Process Running Locally"
    fi 
    fi

# If the server is back up and no alert is sent - alert
elif [ $CS -eq 0 ] && [ $FAILED -eq 1 ]
then
    FAILED=0
    if [ $DEBUG -eq 1 ]
    then
    echo "$SERVER is back up"
    fi
    if [ $DEBUG = 0 ]
    then
    echo "$SERVER is back up $(date)" | /usr/bin/mail -s "$SERVER is back up again" "$SENDEREMAIL" "$SMSEMAIL"
    echo "$SERVER is back up $(date)" | /usr/bin/mail -s "$SERVER is back up again" "$SENDEREMAIL" "$NOTIFYEMAIL"
    fi
fi
sleep $PAUSE
done
```

I have to execute my server with `sudo` in order to use port `:80` so I am executing the script like:

```
sudo ./outage.sh
```

Of course, warnings, suggestions, improvements are welcome.

One improvement I'm interested in implementing is to iterate through a list of servers in order to keep track of multiple web sites.

Comment: Well I've already found one likely flaw with this script which is that when the server gets restarted, I'm not sure what happens with this one - i think it stops running or at least is blocked, as opposed to spawning a separate process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Indent code blocks

To improve readability,
it's good to indent code blocks in loops and if statements.
For example:

```
while true
do
    /usr/bin/curl -sSf --max-time 10 $SERVER > /dev/null 2>&1
    CS=$?
```

You indented some if statements, but not all. Indent all.

#### Replace `elif` with `else` if possible

In these conditions:

> ```
>     if [ $CS -ne 0 ]
>     then
>     echo "$SERVER is down"
>
>     elif [ $CS -eq 0 ]
>     then
>     echo "$SERVER is up"
> ```

If `$CS` is not-not-zero, then when can it be? Zero, of course!
So the `elif` can be a simple `else`.

#### Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``

`` `...` `` is old-fashioned and error prone. Use `$(...)` instead.

#### `ps ... | grep ... | grep -v grep`

Instead of:

> ```
> ps -eaf | grep 'python -m fore.server' | grep -v grep
> ```

A common workaround is:

> ```
> ps -eaf | grep '[p]ython -m fore.server'
> ```

This works, because this way in the output of `ps`, the process `python -m fore.server` will still match, but `grep '[p]ython -m fore.server'` will not match.

However, in this particular example you should go a bit further, see the next point.

#### Look suspiciously at `grep` in a pipeline ending with `awk`

`awk` is fast and powerful,
and very often can easily do `grep`'s job too when it's in the same pipeline.

For example instead of this:

> ```
> ps -eaf | grep 'python -m fore.server' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
> ```

You can rewrite the whole thing using `awk` alone:

```
ps -eaf | awk '/python -m fore.server/ {print $2}'
```

This is not only shorter and less troublesome (no need for the `grep [p]ython` trick),
and there are less processes executed in the pipeline.

#### Don't repeat yourself

You do some things twice, with identical or very similar commands:

- Finding the PID of the Python process
- Sending an email with the message that the server is down
- Sending an email with the message that the server is back up

It would be better to move common operations to helper functions.

#### Other simplifications

Instead of this:

> ```
>     if [[ "" !=  "$PID" ]]
> ```

You can write as:

```
    if [[ $PID ]]
```

Comment: wow. that's a lot to take in at my level of bash. have barely cracked the surface of awk yet.